# Do parallel computing packages such as doSNOW/doParallel help when I'm using Microsoft R open?

Tags: r, doparallel, microsoft-r

I'm using Microsoft R Open, which embeds parallel computing in its backend. Just curious if using  parallel computing packages `doSNOW`/`doParallel` with `foreach` would still improve computational performance on top of that? Or it would actually cause some conflicts and slow down the computation?

Comment: Have you done any benchmarking of your own? The answer is almost certainly going to be *"it depends"*. It depends on what you are doing. If it's something that the Intel MKL can help multi-thread, then almost certainly "yes". If it's something more complex, then likely it adds little or nothing over non-Microsoft R.

Comment: Take a look here : https://mran.microsoft.com/documents/rro/multithread